# Locking a file for multiple programs to access

Tags: winapi, locking, mutex

I've got two Win32 programs: "program A", a web interface, and "program B", a worker program, that operate on a collection of files.  "Program A" tells "program B" to perform an operation on a set of files, "program B" does it, and signals to "program A" that it's done.

Now, here's the situation: there might be multiple "program A"s and "program B"s on different computers, accessing files stored on a network share.  I need to ensure that only one "program B" is accessing a set of files at a time.

I could do it using lock files, but those have issues (such as not going away if the owning process crashes) that I'd need to deal with.  I don't think I can use traditional file locking, since my architecture requires "program A" to control the locking while "program B" accesses the files.  Is there a solution I'm not seeing, such as a "network-wide mutex"?

Comment: Why not have one "Program B" that interacts with the files running on the host?  All other "Program A"'s connect to it through a network socket and tell it to start working.

Comment: @psyklopz, "Program B" is an existing program with about 20 years of ossified design decisions embedded in it (among other things, it is very strongly single-threaded).  The operations it performs are also rather CPU-intensive, so I will probably need to run copies on multiple servers to manage the load.

Comment: Sounds like you need a database. It looks like you are attempting to implement one yourself, and by the sounds of it, a rather flimsy one. You really should not be attempting to reinvent this particular wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock files should be all you need.  You just need to choose semantics that say "this set of files is locked by someone else if I can't open the associated lock file for exclusive access" rather than "this set of files is locked by someone else if the associated lock file exists".

You could still run into problems requiring admin intervention if one of the worker servers crashes (the entire server, not your program) but that should be rare enough that this is OK; just make sure your logic raises some sort of alarm if any  particular set of files is locked for an excessively long time.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the "Lock File" using `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` this should actually delete the file even if the process crashes. (I'm not completely sure this also happens on network drives however).